# Opening default SMS app via a textview

Tags: android, eclipse, sms

I would like to open the **default SMS app** via a `TextView`. I have a rough idea of how I will do this but am not 100% sure. I have looked up multiple tutorials and questions on this and non of them cover this as simply as it is.

It's mainly the `Java` side of things I am having trouble with. I have set-up the class I want the code to go in and have set up the **XML** `textview` to respond to `Onclicks`.

just having a little trouble with what the code would look like in **Java**, thanks.

Updated code, getting an error on "context", "text","phoneNumber" and "smsOnClicklistener". The error I am getting is nothing can be resolved to a variable:

```
package com.youtube.iamjackpot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfomenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_infomenu);

    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    smsOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(smsIntent,"SMS:"));
        }

    };

}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to get a hold of the `TextView` that you want to make clickable. You do this by using the reference of the `TextView` as such:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
```

When you have the reference you can set an `OnClickListener` to it, so that when it's clicked the OnClickListener will be fired off, like so:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(smsOnClickListener);
```

The `OnClickListener` in your case should look something like:

```
smsOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(smsIntent, "SMS:"));
    }
```

}

Good luck! :) And this is my first post to StackOverFlow hopefully it won't be the last one!

Comment: When I use the code you gave me, I get an error on "context", "text","phoneNumber" and "smsOnClicklistener". The error I am getting is nothing can be resolved to a variable. I have added my code in my answer above, see if you can see what the issue is, thanks.

Comment: Hey Jaack, thanks for adding your code. The variables phoneNumber and text are actually variables. So the phone-number should be a string contaning a phone number and the text will be the "body" of the sms. So create two variables, phoneNumber and text containing the number of the user you want to send the text to and the actual text. The variable context is actually the "context" where you are starting your intent from, so you can this "this" if you are in an activity. so, this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(smsIntent, "SMS:")) should do it.¨

Answer (score 1):

Onclick of the text view do the following:

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", phno);
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(smsIntent, "SMS:"));
```