# How to open default message app in my android application?

Tags: android

This is my code

```
   private Button emailBtn;/* button object
private Button smsBtn;  */


    smsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.msg_btn);*/ layout       
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        }
    });
    smsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.sms");

            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening default SMS app via a textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570490/opening-default-sms-app-via-a-textview)

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` event of that button.It will open default sms app

```
smsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424224/my-footer-view-cannot-be-visible-in-output-of-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

PFA the latest solution to open a message application (Kotlin):

```
  val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
  sendIntent.data = Uri.parse("sms:"+issue.number)
  mContext.startActivity(sendIntent)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can implement this code on button click event.

```
Intent n = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
n.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
n.putExtra("address", "1234567890");
n.putExtra("sms_body","Hello EveryBody!!!");
startActivity(n);
```

Comment: Help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424224/my-footer-view-cannot-be-visible-in-output-of-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android